# No module named pip.req

Tags: python, pip, tweepy

I am installing tweepy, but I am running into an error about pip.req. I have pip installed, but for  some reason pip.req still can't be found. I did a bunch of research online and the most I could find was some issue about incompatibilities between zapo (?) and python 2.7 causing the same error for some other user. The discussion was unclear about how to solve the problem, though. Thanks!

```
$ python2 setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pip.req import parse_requirements
ImportError: No module named pip.req
```

Comment: Looks like they wanted to remove it.  I don't entirely agree with the decision, but here is the PR to remove that module from pip 10.
https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/4700

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It looks like it would work if you had this code:

```
def parse_requirements(filename):
    """ load requirements from a pip requirements file """
    lineiter = (line.strip() for line in open(filename))
    return [line for line in lineiter if line and not line.startswith("#")]
```

Do this:

1. create a directory `pip/`
2. add an empty file `pip/__init__.py`
3. add a file `pip/req.py`
4. put the code above into `pip/req.py`:
5. modify the line in `setup.py`

   reqs = install_reqs

Comment: ^ Thanks! So I can understand - why is that? Why is it that I have to add in this code myself and what does the code above do?

Comment: The author of tweepy wrote a `setup.py`script that references files and directories that don't exist. I am telling you what the author probably meant. (Chances are, these files are on his hard drive but not added to the git repo. It happens.) This code reads a pip `requirements.txt` file and extracts the desired modules to install. Then `setup.py` actually installs the files.

Comment: @hughdbrown what line should I modify and by what?

Comment: @AliIssa I would recommend placing the function in the setup.py file rather than importing it. See my solution below.

Comment: Hi @hughdbrown, can you tell me the location of setup.py file that your talking about. Im really new to django/python

Comment: It is not entirely clear where to add the line `reqs=install_reqs` in the `setup.py` file, so I am stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 158):

This is happening lately because of a change in pip 10.

The fix is pretty easy. You probably have something like:

```
from pip.req import parse_requirements
```

Change that to something like:

```
try: # for pip >= 10
    from pip._internal.req import parse_requirements
except ImportError: # for pip <= 9.0.3
    from pip.req import parse_requirements
```

That should do it.

Comment: Why'd they not add backwards compatibility. A lot of packages will fail installing with this error. :(

Comment: Seems like they regretted that this was available, since they moved it to the private namespace of `_internals`. But yeah, not nice to take it away.

Comment: @kororo, I think you're reading the date as "April 2016" instead of as 16 April 2018 (the current year).

Comment: The pip developers did not ever intend to vend API, but to be a tool only.

Comment: Being shockingly few people, they didn't have a lot of time and energy to build an amazing transition plan. It blows my mind that the HUGE Python community contributes so little to what the tiny group of pip developers do.

Comment: Thank you, this was very usefull =D

Answer (score 55):

I downgraded to pip to 9.0.3 and things worked for me.
Command for downgrading pip is

```
python -m pip install pip==9.0.3
```

Comment: Thanks. It's sad it came to downgrading pip, but that's the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

I had a very similar problem with Python 3.7 + pip 18.0:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip-compile", line 7, in <module>
    from piptools.scripts.compile import cli
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/piptools/scripts/compile.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip.req import InstallRequirement, parse_requirements
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.req'
```

The solution was to upgrade pip-tools from 1.10 to 2.0:

```
pip install -U pip-tools
```

Comment: I had the same problem with pip-tools today (alô Humberto!)

Comment: `from pip._internal.req import parse_requirements`

Answer (score 9):

Instead of importing the function and potentially encountering more issues replace the contents of the setup.py with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#from distutils.core import setup
import re, uuid
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

def parse_requirements(filename):
    """ load requirements from a pip requirements file """
    lineiter = (line.strip() for line in open(filename))
    return [line for line in lineiter if line and not line.startswith("#")]


VERSIONFILE = "tweepy/__init__.py"
ver_file = open(VERSIONFILE, "rt").read()
VSRE = r"^__version__ = ['\"]([^'\"]*)['\"]"
mo = re.search(VSRE, ver_file, re.M)

if mo:
    version = mo.group(1)
else:
    raise RuntimeError("Unable to find version string in %s." % (VERSIONFILE,))

install_reqs = parse_requirements('requirements.txt')
reqs = install_reqs

setup(name="tweepy",
      version=version,
      description="Twitter library for python",
      license="MIT",
      author="Joshua Roesslein",
      author_email="tweepy@googlegroups.com",
      url="http://github.com/tweepy/tweepy",
      packages=find_packages(exclude=['tests']),
      install_requires=reqs,
      keywords="twitter library",
      classifiers=[
          'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
          'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries',
          'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
          'Operating System :: OS Independent',
          'Programming Language :: Python',
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.6',
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.3',
          'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.4',
      ],
      zip_safe=True)
```

Notice the session argument has been removed from the parse_requirements call.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into same problem you have. To install pip you need to follow this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools once you get easy_install I installed pip first and then run the following command.

```
sudo easy_install pip
sudo python setup.py install
```

easy.