# Python - Tweepy Module - pip.req

Tags: python, module, tweepy

When I am trying to install tweepy module for python on windows 7, I type in easy_install tweepy
and it gives me the error of:
ImportError: No module named pip.req

I already read the link below but I am a newbie and didnt understand it:
[No module named pip.req](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192794/no-module-named-pip-req)
PLEASE HELP!!

Answer (score 1):

You should look inside the file `setup.py` in your folder with downloaded `tweepy`.
There you could find the line:

```
from pip.req import parse_requirements
```

`setup.py` tries to import `parse_requirements` function from module `req` from package `pip`.
But inside `tweepy` folder there are no `pip` package with `req.py` python module. Read about Python packages and modules [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages).
So you need to do the steps from the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25193001/821093 to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simply one line command as suggested by [Tweepy installation](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy#installation)

Or you can [download](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy) the file yourself and put on your desktop (or wherever you like). From the windows command type:

1. cd deskstop\tweepy-master # tweepy-mast is defaul name from the zip download
2. python steup.py install

You can access the command prompt window using the "Window key" + "R" then type "cmd".