# ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'pip.req'

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to push my python web app in IBM Cloud but I got this error.

[image]

Upon digging to the error this is what I got.

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "run.py", line 1, in 
>   from flaskblog import app File "/home/vcap/app/flaskblog/**init**.py",
>   line 19, in  from flaskblog import routes
>
> File "/home/vcap/app/flaskblog/routes.py", line 6, in  import
>   pandas as pd ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas' Exit status
>   1

[image]

Comment: An answer was provided below; you should give feedback on whether this solved your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No module named pip.req](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192794/no-module-named-pip-req)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means your "flaskblog" code uses the pandas library, but that library is not installed. You have to install it in your target environment so the code can use it.