# Error while installing django-google-address

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-3.6

I want to add location feature on my django project. In internet I found, I have to run `pip install django-google-address` first.
This gives an error, how to solve this?

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info: ERROR: 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h0qlrtha\django-google-address\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
      from pip.req import parse_requirements ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.req'
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h0qlrtha\django-google-address\
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Because I think it might be that you're trying to use Python 2 which does not work with django-google-address (as stated [here](https://github.com/leonardoarroyo/django-google-address/issues/1))

Comment: @Charlie I am using Python version 3.6

Comment: Could you provide the whole output of `pip`? Or is that it?

Comment: @Charlie    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h0qlrtha\django-google-address\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        from pip.req import parse_requirements
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip.req'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-h0qlrtha\django-google-address\

Comment: That appears to be [this unfixed issue](https://github.com/leonardoarroyo/django-google-address/issues/4). I don't know how one would fix that. Maybe you could try with a different version of pip (notably pip <= 10)

Comment: Please update all the details in your question and not in the comments.

Comment: Please mention pip version by running command `pip --version`

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip3 install django-google-address` as this might be related to the version of python.

You might need to recreate some files as mentioned under [No module named pip.req](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192794/no-module-named-pip-req/28725142)

Comment: Can I know the error you get while executing pip3 or pip?

Comment: Can you try `python -m pip install –upgrade pip` to upgrade the pip version if it is an issue with that (But most possibly it won't). But there is a workaround. You may refer the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192794/no-module-named-pip-req/28725142