# Can't install flask-ask: error from cryptography module

Tags: python, flask, pip, python-3.8, flask-ask

The pip command to install `flask-ask` is simply:

```
pip install flask-ask
```

However, when I run this command, I get this error:
[image]

Now, I have heard that you can simply downgrade your pip version to circumvent this error. However, when I do this, I get an error from the cryptography module:
[image]

I have tried fully updating pip, changing Python from 32-bit to 64-bit and I'm still unable to install `flask-ask`.

Could someone help me to get this module installed?

Comment: Please paste these snippets into the question directly as code-formatted text. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at this SO answer?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192794/no-module-named-pip-req